# Why don't they send the files through the mail channel?

Tags: 24

In the series *24*, season 4, episode 12, as Jack Bauer is in the corporation building restoring deleted files, why don't they send those files via the given mail channel opened with Tony Almeda, but trying to print it?

Comment: which season is this?

Comment: This sounds like series 4: Jack and Paul Raines are at McLennen-Forster trying to recover some encrypted files when they set off an EMP to destroy the computer system.

Comment: season 4, added it